# How to get current neo4j session after SDN upgrade to 4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT?

Tags: session, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

After updating Spring Data Neo4j to `4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` several difficulties appeared. In particular, I need to get current `Session` instance to perform some custom query. I've been doing this using

```
private Neo4jOperations getNeo4jOperations() {
    return applicationContext.getBean(Neo4jOperations.class);
}
```

but `Neo4jOperations` is now deprecated, so I tried

```
private Session Neo4jSession() {
    return applicationContext.getBean(SessionFactory.class).openSession();
}
```

but got an exception:

```
org.neo4j.ogm.exception.TransactionManagerException: Transaction is not current for this thread
    org.neo4j.ogm.session.transaction.DefaultTransactionManager.rollback(DefaultTransactionManager.java:93)
    org.neo4j.ogm.transaction.AbstractTransaction.rollback(AbstractTransaction.java:67)
    org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.transaction.BoltTransaction.rollback(BoltTransaction.java:64)
    org.neo4j.ogm.transaction.AbstractTransaction.close(AbstractTransaction.java:141)
    org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.Neo4jTransactionManager.doCleanupAfterCompletion(Neo4jTransactionManager.java:311)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.cleanupAfterCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:1016)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:811)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:487)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy110.delete(Unknown Source)
```

So how can I get a current session instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you try this?
Note that this config is using spring-data-neo4j `4.2.0.M1` version, but I think it should work for `4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` as well

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return new SessionFactory(getConfiguration(), "com.yourbasepackage") {
    };
}

@Bean
@Scope(value = "prototype", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public Session getSession() throws Exception {
    return getSessionFactory().openSession();
}
```

Also annotate your config class with:

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
```

Then you can inject the `session` bean and use it whatever you want:

```
@Inject
Session session;
```

You can see the upgrade to SDN 4.2 complete guide [here](http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2016/09/30/upgrading-to-sdn-42.html).

> ***NOTE***: Due to another issue, I've recently created a sample project on
>   [github](https://github.com/troig/neo4jCustomRepository) configured correctly with this version of
>   `spring-data-neo4j`. I think it could help you as a configuration
>   sample.

Hope it helps

Comment: Great answer @troig! Just one thing: you don't need to define a `getSession()` bean anymore.. just the `Neo4jTransactionManager`: See: http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2016/09/30/upgrading-to-sdn-42.html @Polyakoff: just be sure to surround any calls made with the injected `Session` with `@Transactional` otherwise you may still see the same exception. :)